# glassfish server on openshift is not working

Tags: java, glassfish, openshift

I am trying to deploy the glassfish server on openshift do it yourself gear. I have tried every possible solution. firstly from this https://blog.openshift.com/running-java-apps-in-the-cloud-with-glassfish-and-a-paas/ then from this https://github.com/shekhargulati/glassfish4-openshift-quickstart this https://github.com/a-boy/openshift-glassfish4-quickstart and also this http://svanimpe.be/blog/glassfish-openshift.html but not a single one is helping.

I am getting this error message

remote: -------------------------

remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure

remote: Activation status: failure

remote: Activation failed for the following gears:

remote: ************************ (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/************************/diy

remote: #

remote: #

remote: )

remote: Deployment completed with status: failure

remote: postreceive failed

Is there any other solution.? I need it ASAP.